# Python encoding blocks of text using strings

Tags: python, encryption, encoding

**The question I've been set is:**
"For encoding blocks of text it is easier to work with strings than numbers, in order to avoid problems with leading zeros.
So, we will need a function like `code_digit(n, key)` that works with characters instead of numbers.
To that end, write a function `code_char(char, key)` that works like `code_digit(n, key)` except that its parameters are characters, both of which are assumed to be in the range ’0’ to ’9’, not integers, and it returns a character.

So for example

```
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼>>> code_char('1', '2')    
'3'
```

My Code

```
def code_char(char, key):
    ichar = int(char)
    ikey = int(key)
    print(ichar+ikey)
```

That's the furthest I got but the quotation marks aren't there.

```
>>> code_char('1', '2')
3
```

Any help would be appreciated!
`code_digit` function is as follows:

```
def code_digit(n, key):
    result = n + key
    mod = result%10
    print (mod)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing two things wrongly on your code:

- You're printing the result instead of returning it. Also, printing a `chr` or `str` don't add quotation marks around it.
- You're never converting the result back to a `chr` or `str`.

So, your code should be something like this:

```
def code_char(char, key):
    ichar = int(char)
    ikey = int(key)
    return str(ichar+ikey)
```

or

```
def code_char(char, key):
    ichar = int(char)
    ikey = int(key)
    return chr(ord('0') + ichar+ikey)
```